# Merging multiple files into one JSON file in Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I’m working on a pipeline in ADF and i would like to get business metadata from one source and technical metadata from Oracle.

How can i merge those two files into one model.JSON in Azure Data Factory?

Comment: You mean you need to merge the file from two sources, one source is technical metadata from Oracle, what's the another ?

Comment: The other JSON File is located in a container (ADLS Gen2).

Answer (score 1):

You could Union those 2 sources together as a single model using data flows and design your new combined output schema using a Derived Column